# How to inherit java classes (from one package) into another class (in another package)

Tags: java, inheritance

Java n00b here. I have been learning about packages lately and see them as really useful in managing code. However, I am (frequently) running into a problem of not being able to inherit a class from one package into a class of another package.

Here's the code of `A.java` which has been created in `Package1`:-

```
package Package1;
public class A
{
    private int a;

    protected void setA(int a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public int getA()
    {
        return a;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("a = "+a);
    }
}
```

The class that is inheriting is `A1.java` located in `Package2`. Its code is as follows:-

```
package Package2;
import Package1.A;
public class A1 extends A      // I even tried `Package1.A` but didn't have any change
{
    private int a1;

    public void setA1(int a1)
    {
        this.a1 = a1;
    }

    public int getA1()
    {
        return a1;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("a1 = "+a1);
    }
}
```

The error that I am getting is:-

```
A1.java:2: error: package Package1 does not exist
import Package1.A;
               ^
A1.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
public class A1 extends A
                        ^
  symbol: class A
```

OR

```
A1.java:2: error: package Package1 does not exist
import Package1.A;
               ^
A1.java:3: error: package Package1 does not exist
public class A1 extends Package1.A
```

I am not understanding how to solve this problem. Can you please help?

Comment: How are you compiling the source code? Is `A` on the classpath?

Comment: `javac A1.java` (inside Package2). The other way of compiling is `javac -d . A1.java` but that is used when A1.java is not in the package.

Comment: You need to provide a `-cp` option with the location of the `class` files your program depends on, ie. `package1`.

Comment: Why do I need to use classpath? I thought it depends on the access specifiers only.

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know where to find the `class` file for your class `A`? You need to tell it where it is.

Comment: may sound stupid, but is A inside a directory called Package1 and A1 inside a directory called Package2?

Comment: @Leo Yes. Both `A.java` and `A.class` are inside `Package1`. Similarily `A1.java` and `A1.class` are inside `Package2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in your -cp parameter: the compiler can't find your class A

After you've understood the raw basics of classpath (and some memory settings), you should definitely use a java editor to start, you will loose a lot of time in compiling manually and understand the compiler which doesn't bring you anything as a skill.

Later you will maybe use some more sophisticated compiling tools (and a lot more than compiling when you will do "continuous integration"): yous can start looking at Gradle and Maven (Gradle is the new way of doing but many companies still use Maven, so if you think you'll search for a job learn maven, if you want to be effective, learn Gradle)

Eclipse is THE free Java editor, so that's what I recommend you : http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/keplersr1

p.s: also packages should have lower case names, avoid using numbers in your names

Comment: `understand the compiler which doesn't bring you anything as a skill` You should absolutely know how the compiler works.

Comment: Why? I'm a java expert. Unless I would need to write my own compiler, I don't need to understand how it works to write code. You have tools like GUIs, maven, ant, gradle etc... that will handle compiling for you. Beleive me or not (search for Zied Hamdi on google, I worked for the biggest companies as a Java open source expert, and I don't know all the options of the compiler: the Agile way is to learn only what you need)

Comment: I obviously don't mean _know the compiler's every detail_. But I think it's important to know how classes are linked through the class path. This is true for `javac` as much as it is for `java`. Sure, IDEs and build systems help, but if you don't configure them correctly, you'll still get all the errors that are described in OP's question. It would be good to know how to fix them.

Comment: Also, learning about the compiler helps you learn about the language itself and that's always a plus.

Comment: packages with uppercase names are specially a problem when you work with windows and linux with the same project ;-)

Comment: You can also learn how each class is written, and how the GUI works, and how the mouse works. It's all plus, but it costs you time and you find yourself knowing things you don't need

Comment: Look Sotirios, I wrote an open source here (https://code.google.com/p/advanced-suggest-select-box/), the java code is compiled to many javascripts versions (one for each browser). Do you really think I went to look into the Google compiler code to understand how it works?
it works, and you must rely on it

Comment: (You can reply to someone with @username). Again, I don't mean knowing the intricacies of a compiler implementation, but knowing the [different options for the `javac` command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html) and when to use them will definitely be helpful.

Comment: Ok, the recommended way for real projects (very often: the requirements) is to use a building framework usually Maven and recently Gradle. You will be better off learning these tools as compiling automates rather than using the raw javac. I'm feeling you want to show you know what you are doing, I was just doing my pause and I thought I will help some people. I'm not confronting with you, do it as you want, you have an expert advice, you are a beginner so, either you welcome advices, or just keep it your way, I won't loose anything. The compiler is not made to be called manually

Comment: But just to answer your 'original' question: you have a problem in your -cp parameter: the compiler can't find your class A

Comment: That's what you should, primarily, put in your answer (edit it). For sure, use the appropriate build tools when you can, but don't use them without knowing what they are doing. That's a recipe for disaster. Sure I can run `mvn clean install`, but am I doing it because I was told to or because I know that's what I have to do to compile and package my application? What are maven dependencies, how are they managed? All these questions have answers in the Java compiler.

Comment: That's more like it :)

Comment: You started your post by saying: "Java n00b here" so I answered accordingly to the audience. If you want to check further, you should know the java compiler is written in Java, you can check what is happening there too

Comment: The post started by saying: "Java n00b here" I thought you @SotiriosDelimanolis asked the question until now, that's why I was wondering why you're resisting this way instead of getting the answer :)